# Can't access layout from a nested package folder in android

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I have a folder structure like this (android view):

```
com.sampleproject
--api
--projectname
  --fragments
    --Frag1.java
  --adapters
    --ArrayAdapter1.java
  --MainActivity.java

--res
  --layout
    --fragment_sample.xml
    --main_activity.xml
```

I can access `fragment_sample` from `MainActivity` by simply writing `R.layout.fragment_sample` but the layout cannot be resolved when I try to access it from `ArrayAdapter1` or `Frag1`

Can anyone explain why that is?

Comment: try giving the context of MainActivity.mInstance.findviewbyId(R.id.yourFragmentLayout);

Comment: I will try that but why can't I access the resources directly anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1:Make sure your ArrayAdapter1 and Frag1 have com.sampleproject.projectname.R;
2:Pass MainActivity.this to ArrayAdapter1 and Frag1.

Comment: I just figured this out. This was the error on my part.